# Search and replace if statements without braces to include braces

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've been recently using sonar for code analysis. When I go thorough violation drilldown, I found many java files with if statement defined without braces (thousands of places). Is there a simple way to replace or add braces to if statements or what are the steps that I can perform to achieve this task without doing it manually in each of the files.

I'm currently using intelliJ.

Comment: If they're just all single statement conditions why would you bother?

Comment: @BenStephens Because some developers -- *like me* -- can't stand `if` statements without braces ..?

Comment: @BenStephens just to remove those violation messages. The code is running fine, but I was asked to do that.

Comment: Can you just change the "formatting/code style" rules apply those? (ReSharper, also by JetBrains, would allow this I believe .. [also make sure to *disallow* other/unwanted formatting rules])

Comment: @pst then you're crazy...  I can't stand when half the screen is taken up by braces which didn't need to be there :)  But then I like oneliners too like if (foo) dobar();

Comment: @BenStephens The class of bugs created by not using braces isn't worth the single extra line of the closing brace.

Comment: I'm with @pst; this is a code formatting option and IntelliJ will add braces for you when you format the source.

Comment: If adding them unnecessarily gets people past the inepitude involved in being unable to read program flow then awesome... PS I found this about Sonar [SONAR-560] – Deactivate checkstyle rule "Need Braces" in "Sonar Way" rules profile    --   Unsure if this means in version 1.6 they've turned off the check to force you to use braces... or turned off the option to ignore them..  but if you're not already > v1.6 then might be worth looking into

Comment: @BenStephens I can reformat the code to make intelliJ do the thing for me, but I need to go through all the files and reformat it. Yes, I might turned off the check but wondering if there is a good tool to do the task. I've good set of tests to check whether it introduce bugs during the process.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a simple way to replace or add braces to if statements or what are the steps that I can perform to achieve this task without doing it manually in each of the files.

I don't know if there is a tool to do this automatically.  (There probably is ...)  But assuming that such a tool exists, I'm not convinced it would be the right approach.

Step back for a moment and consider why the code analysis has reported this as a problem.  A lot of people (like @pst and me) think that the braces always should be there, even though various style guides don't insist on this.  There is a good reason for this ... apart from  "it looks ugly".  Consider these example code snippets:

```
if (i == 1) 
    i++;
    doSomething();

while (i < 1)
    i++;
    doSomething();
```

If you don't read those carefully, your eyes will trick you into thinking that `doSomething();` is called conditionally ... due to the incorrect indentation.  And it happens.

(Aside: labelling someone as "inept" for misreading that code is not helpful.  If you are desperately trying to fix a show-stopper bug and you've been working for 14 hours straight, then you are likely to miss this kind of thing.  And not because you are inept.  Once you've been in that situation a couple of times, the lesson sinks in ...)

OK, now suppose that you run an automatic tool to add the braces.  What you will get is this:

```
 if (i == 1) {
    i++;
 }
    doSomething();

 while (i < 1) {
    i++;
 }
    doSomething();
```

It means exactly the same thing as the original code.  **BUT** ... what if the original code was actually a bug?  What if the programmer *intended* the `doSomething()` calls to be conditional?

In short, by adding the braces automatically, we've obscured the original programmer's intention, and made these bug(s) harder to track down.

---

Bottom line - I think it would be *prudent* to *manually* review each of these occurrences ... rather than just "fixing" them automatically.   Indeed, I'd argue that if you don't have the time or patience to review them manually, it would be better to leave the code alone.  It would be better to turn off the warning ... IMO.

Comment: Good answer, though I'd say could use a tool to add the braces around the first statement automatically and it won't change the behaviour of the program.  Assuming of course program already behaves as intended since this isn't a bug finding thing so much as a retrospective style guide change

Comment: Wise words +1. BTW, did you mean `i++`?

Comment: Well yah but focused on the negative aspect, so just pointing out in this case since program (I assume) isn't buggy atm in this particular case it's probably pretty safe to just use a tool.  In any case great answer :)

Comment: @StephenC I fully agree with you. But I want to see if there is any tool for this purpose?

Comment: @darkapple - I can't help you on that.

Comment: @BenStephens - You think it is ok to *assume* that the program isn't buggy?  The whole point of my answer is that you CAN'T assume that!

Comment: @darkapple - *"I've good set of tests to check whether it introduce bugs during the process."*.  That is moot.  The tool won't introduce any new bugs (unless the tool is itself buggy).  The problem is with the bugs that are already in your code-base, and are not currently being picked up by your test suite.  Now, I'll grant you that there is a good chance that there won't be any bugs of this nature (see above) in your code.  But you've got no easy way of quantifying the risk.

Comment: I think it is yes, we can't all agree and there's merit to being cautious however in this case the asker stated the program runs as expected, they have some kind of unit tests or something like it and, if it turns out there was a bug in there they need to find later the fact the brace has been added or not is irrelevant, the debugger is still going to need to actually read the code. However I'm gathering we all might have different definitions of reading code.  I would say it's more dangerous in any situation to skim over code, missing things like the lack of braces around indented code blocks

Comment: This all said... I don't want to detract from the answer provided by StephenC... in particular at the end.  It'd be best to just turn off the warnings and leave the code alone.

Answer (score 5):

> I can reformat the code to make intelliJ do the thing for me, but I need to go through all the files and reformat it. Yes, I might turned off the check but wondering if there is a good tool to do the task. I've good set of tests to check whether it introduce bugs during the process.

If you are sure that you have some ways to test that you will not introduce bugs then use the IntelliJ *Reformat Code* feature.

Just make sure that the *Code Style* you have in IntelliJ is in line with your company's policies. Otherwise you will force your style on everybody else too.

To force braces just mark them as `Always` on the *Wrapping and Braces* tag in the *Code Style* settings dialog in IntelliJ.

Mark the source folder in the project view and press `Ctrl-Alt-L`. A dialog pops up and there you can chose `All files in directory <...>`.

Then press `Run` and see what happens. If you are not satisfied then just revert from your VCS.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA has an inspection for this as well, and it has a quick fix to automatically add the braces.

Invoke `Analyze | Run Inspection by Name` and enter inspection name `Control flow statement without braces`. Run it on the desired part of your project. In the inspection results you can apply the quick fix `Add braces to statement`.

Note that this inspection will also report control flow statement other than `if`, like for example `while` statements. Invoking the quick fix will also add braces to those statements.