# IntelliJ structural replace to find all if statements with no braces (having only one line if condition is met), and surround it with braces?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

How can IntelliJ's [structural replace](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/structural-search-and-replace.html) feature be used to find all if statements having exactly one line (that's executed when the condition is met)

```
if (isNice)
   doSomething();
```

and surround them with curly braces?

```
if (isNice) {
   doSomething();
}
```

Surprisingly, this

```
if ($expression$)
   $expression2$;
```

is finding if blocks with *or* without curlys...although I'm not sure this is on the right path to begin with...

Comment: Why don't you use the formatting code feature?

Comment: you may read this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046915/search-and-replace-if-statements-without-braces-to-include-braces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is currently not possible with Structural Search and Replace. There is however a different way to achieve the desired result: the *Control flow statement without braces* inspection. It has a quick fix to add braces.